# I need to keep the values entered by a user after refreshing the webpage

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a form entry web page to store the data entered to a local database . The only problem is that after the submit button is clicked on the form it goes to another file named "info1.php" to store the data in the local database , in that file it also validates if the entered data is valid for example the email . If the data is invalid it refreshes the page to the form entry site or web page "home.php"

It would be much better the same user does not have to enter the whole thing again from the start , But instead the same value previously entered still resides in the web page (ie) form Thanks in Advance guys :-)
The form code is :

```
 <?php
session_start();
 ?>

<head>
<php
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Data Entry Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300'      rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
    <body>
     <form action="info1.php" method="post">
      <h1>DATA ENTRY</h1>
     <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name"  required/>
      <label for="rollnumber">Roll number</label>
      <input type="text" id="rollnum" name="roll_number" required/>
       <label for="batch">Batch</label>
        <select id="batch" name="user_batch" required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="2013-2017">2013-2017</option>
        <option value="2014-2018">2014-2018</option>
        <option value="2015-2019">2015-2019</option>
        <option value="2016-2020">2016-2020</option>
           </select>
       </fieldset>

     <label for="from">Came from</label>
    <select id="from" name="user_from" required/>

          <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="+2">+2</option>
        <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>
                       </select>

   <label for="year">Year</label>
    <select id="year" name="user_year" required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
           </select>
      <label for="level">Level</label>
    <select id="level" name="user_level"required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="UG">UG</option>
        <option value="PG">PG</option>

           </select>
           <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" id="email_id" name="email_id" required/>
           <label for="name">Father`s Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="F_name" required/>
       <label for="name">Mother`s Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="mname" name="m_name" required/>
      <label for="name">Guardian`s Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="gname" name="g_name" >
       <label for="mob_number">Students Mobile Number</label>
      <input type="number" id="mob_number" name="mob_number"required/>

     </select>
           <label for="addressline1">Address Line 1</label>
      <input type="text" id="addressline1" name="addressline1" required/>

       </select>
           <label for="addressline2">Address Line2</label>
      <input type="text" id="addressline2" name="addressline2" required/>

        </select>
           <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type="text" id="city" name="city" required/>


        <label for="pmobnumber">Parents Mobile Number</label>
      <input type="number" id="pmob_num" name="pmob_number" required/>
       <label for="landnumber">LandLine Number or Parents Number</label>
      <input type="number" id="landnum" name="land_number"required/>


      <label for="cutoff">+2 cutoff</label>
      <input type="number" id="cutoff" name="cutoff">


       <label for="dept">Department</label>
    <select id="dept" name="dept" required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="CSE">CSE</option>
        <option value="IT">IT</option>
        <option value="ECE">ECE</option>
        <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
        <option value="MECH">MECH</option>
        <option value="CIVIL">CIVIL</option>
           </select>

      <label for="medium">Medium of Instruction</label>
    <select id="medium" name="medium"required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="ENGLISH">English</option>
        <option value="TAMIL">Tamil</option>

           </select>

        <label for="locality">Locality</label>
    <select id="locality" name="locality"required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="RURAL">Rural</option>
        <option value="URBAN">Urban</option>

           </select>


        <label for="intrest">Intrested In</label>
    <select id="intrest" name="intrest"required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="PLACEMENTS">Placements</option>
        <option value="HIGHER STUDIES">Higher Studies</option>
         <option value="Entrepreneurship">Entrepreneurship</option>

           </select>


           <label for="scholar">Scholarship</label>
    <select id="scholar" name="scholar"required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="GOVERNMENT">Government</option>
        <option value="PRIVATE">Private</option>

           </select>


           <label for="income">Parents Annual Income</label>
    <select id="income" name="income" required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="Less than 50,000">Less than 50,000</option>
        <option value="Less than 1,00,000">Less than 1,00,000</option>
        <option value="Less than 2,00,000">Less than 2,00,000</option>
        <option value="Less than 5,00,000">Less than 5,00,000</option>
        <option value="Less than 10,00,000">Less than 10,00,000</option>
        <option value="OTHERS">others</option>
           </select>


      <label for="year">Caste</label>
    <select id="caste" name="user_caste" required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="OC">OC</option>
        <option value="BC">BC</option>
        <option value="MBC">MBC</option>
        <option value="BCM">BCM</option>
        <option value="SC">SC</option>
        <option value="ST">ST</option>
           </select>
           <label for="admit">Admitted through</label>
    <select id="admit" name="user_admit"required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="Government Quota">Government Quota</option>
        <option value="Manegement Quota">Manegement Quota</option>
                        </select>
         <label for="stay">Staying In</label>

    <select id="stay" name="user_stay"required/>

        <option value="NoneSelected">---Click to Select---</option>
        <option value="With parents">With parents</option>
        <option value="College Hostel">College Hostel</option>
        <option value="Outside Room">Outside Room</option>

           </select>

    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" onclick="phonenumber(pmob_number)">ENTER     DATA</button>
  </form>


  <script src="js/mob_valid.js"></script>

</body>
```

The code for the file info1.php is:

```
  <?php 
  $servername = "localhost";  
       $username = "root";  
       $password = "";  
       $conn = mysqli_connect ($servername , $username , $password) or  die("unable to connect to host");  
       $sql = mysqli_select_db ($conn,'vcet') or die("unable to connect to  database"); 


 //code to insert into db...
 $user_name=$_POST['user_name']; 
 $roll_number=$_POST['roll_number'];
 $user_batch=$_POST['user_batch'];
 $user_from=$_POST['user_from'];
 $user_year=$_POST['user_year'];
 $user_level=$_POST['user_level'];
 $email_id=$_POST['email_id'];
 $F_name=$_POST['F_name'];
 $m_name=$_POST['m_name'];
 $g_name=$_POST['g_name'];
 $mob_number=$_POST['mob_number'];
 $addressline1=$_POST['addressline1'];
 $addressline2=$_POST['addressline2'];
 $city=$_POST['city'];
 $pmob_number=$_POST['pmob_number'];
 $land_number=$_POST['land_number'];
 $cutoff=$_POST['cutoff'];
 $dept=$_POST['dept'];
 $medium = $_POST['medium'];
 $locality=$_POST['locality'];
 $intrest=$_POST['intrest'];
 $scholar=$_POST['scholar'];
 $income=$_POST['income'];
 $user_caste=$_POST['user_caste'];
 $user_admit=$_POST['user_admit'];
 $user_stay=$_POST['user_stay'];

if (!filter_var($email_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Sorry...You entered an invalid email id..!!!")';
echo '</script>';
//mysqli_query("delete from studentinfo where roll_number='$roll_number'");
header( "refresh:1;url=http://localhost/DB/home.php" );
}else
{
//executes the rest of the code

$mob_number1=$mob_number;
if(!preg_match('/^\d{10}$/',$mob_number1)) // phone number is valid
{

  echo '<script language="javascript">';
 echo 'alert("Sorry...You entered a wrong Mobile number..!!!")';
 echo '</script>';
 //mysqli_query("delete from studentinfo where roll_number='$roll_number'");
 header( "refresh:1;url=http://localhost/DB/home.php" );

}
else // phone number is  valid
{

    $msg="";

    $num_length = strlen((string)$pmob_number);

    if($num_length!=10){
       echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Sorry...You entered a wrong Mobile number..!!!")';
echo '</script>';
//mysqli_query("delete from studentinfo where roll_number='$roll_number'");
header( "refresh:1;url=http://localhost/DB/home.php" );

    }else
{
 $user_info = "INSERT INTO studentinfo"."  (user_name,roll_number,user_batch,user_from,user_year,user_level,email_id,F_name,m_name,g_name,mob_number,addressline1,addressline2,city,pmob_number,land_number,cutoff,dept,medium,locality,intrest,scholar,income,user_caste,user_admit, user_stay)". "VALUES ('$user_name', '$roll_number','$user_batch','$user_from','$user_year','$user_level','$email_id','$F_name','$m_name','$g_name','".$mob_number."','$addressline1','$addressline2','$city','$pmob_number','$land_number','$cutoff','$dept','$medium','$locality','$intrest','$scholar','$income','$user_caste','$user_admit','$user_stay')"; 
 if (!mysqli_query($conn,$user_info)) { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn)); } echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Awesome!! your INFORMATION  was added to the  DATABASE")';
        echo '</script>';
        header( "refresh:1;url=http://localhost/DB/home.php" ); 
 mysqli_close($conn); 
}

}

}
?>
```

Comment: Save the $_POST values in the SESSION and when you throw back to the data entry page, look in session. If they are there, use the values to reload the input fields with what was previously entered

Comment: You need to set the values as-well, if your reload the page. You didn't implement  that (i.e. add value attributes on input's and set the value on your options). Thats why everything is empty.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry I`m kinda new at this . And I`m not much familiar with using SESSION .  can you give me any example?  . That would be really helpful . Thanks

Comment: Have a look at form validation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RiggsFolly said in the comments, you could use the SESSION to keep the values, to use a SESSION variable, you have to open the session at the beginning of each file where you'll use it.

Basically, on your form page : ( you should ofc check if the $_SESSION['input_value'] var exists )

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['input_value']) {
    $_SESSION['input_value'] = "Default value for this input";
}
?>
some code ...
<input value='<?php echo $_SESSION['input_value']; ?>'>
```

on your form treatment page :

```
<?php session_start();
some code ...
$_SESSION['input_value'] = $_POST['input_value']; // ( or $_GET['input_value'] )
?>
```

Comment: @TklnTky Thanks for your suggestion . But I`m getting this error   Undefined index: input_value     on the text box of the form   ...If so how should i define it?..

Comment: that's why I advised to actually check for it to exists at first, because we only define it once the form has been submitted. So at the beginning of your form page, check if the session variable exists ( with isset() ), and if not, give it an empty value, or the default value for this input.

Comment: @TklnTky Yes that's right . I did name it according to my current file as user_name but still it showed Undefined index: user_name